# Помогите с C#. Индекс находился вне границ массива

Tags: c#

Индекс выходит за пределы массива, где ошибка?

```
string m = textBox1.Text;
string k = textBox2.Text;
char[] orig = { };
string s, b; //Результат
int j, f; // Переменная для циклов
char[] massage = m.ToCharArray(); // Превращаем сообщение в массив символов.
char[] key = k.ToCharArray(); // Превращаем ключ в массив символов.

char[] alfavit = { 'а', 'б', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ё', 'ж', 'з',
'и', 'й', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н',
'о', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'щ', 'ъ',
'ы', 'ь',
'э', 'ю', 'я' };

int i = 0;
int N = alfavit.Length; //Мощность алфавита

//Делаем повторяющийся пароль
b = k;
while (b.Length < m.Length)
{
    b += key[i];
    i++;
}
//Начинаем цикл
for (i = 0; i < massage.Length; i++)
{
    // Ищем индекс буквы
    for (j = 0; j < alfavit.Length; j++)
    {
        if (massage[i] == alfavit[j])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //ищем индекс ключа
    for (q = 0; q < key.Length; q++)
    {
        if (key[q] == alfavit[q])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    //Находим символ исходного сообщения
    orig[i] = Convert.ToChar((massage[i] + N - key[q]) % N);


}
s = new string(orig); // Собираем символы обратно в строку.
textBox3.Text = s.ToString();
```

Вот формула: p<sub>i</sub> = (c<sub>i</sub> + N - k<sub>i</sub>) mod N

p<sub>i</sub> - Символ исходного сообщения

N<sub>i</sub> - Мощность алфавита

k<sub>i</sub> - Символ ключа

с<sub>i</sub> - Символ закодированного сообщения

Comment: Это мы должны спросить у вас где ошибка? На какой строчке она вылетает?

Comment: orig[i] = Convert.ToChar((massage[i] + N - key[q]) % N);
Простите пожалуйста, просто долго оформлял на сайте

Comment: Если в `key` не будет символа из `alfavit`, то цикл пройдет до конца и `q` будет равен `key.Length` и на следующей строчке будет выход за пределы массива. Так же массив `char orig[]` у вас пустой, а вы пытаетесь присвоить `i`-му элементу значение. Выделите память под `message.Length` элементов

Comment: Что мне можно сделать, чтобы это исправить? Я просто новичок)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если в `key` не будет символа из `alfavit`, то цикл пройдет до конца и `q` будет равен `key.Length` и на следующей строчке будет выход за пределы массива.

Перед формулой добавьте проверку на этот случай:

```
if(q != key.Length) производим расчет
else выкидываем исключение
```

Можно выкинуть исключение о том, что символ не найден в алфавите, но тогда на пробеле между словами у вас будет выкидываться исключение, ну или вы можете например добавить его без изменений. Например `"Привет, мир!"` может выглядеть примерно так `"Сткджф, окт!"`.

Так же массив `char[] orig` у вас пустой, а вы пытаетесь присвоить `i`-му элементу значение. Выделите память под `message.Length` элементов.

Ну тут основы языка:

```
char[] orig = new char[m.Length];
```

Comment: Как реализовать исключения? Через новый char?

Comment: Нет, [вот](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.29.php) что это такое. Но пока просто вставляйте без изменений ненайденные символы. Ну или делайте проверки на пробелы и знаки препинания. Хотя вы можете вообще без алфавита написать код и не париться.

Comment: Как мне реализовать, что если символ не найден, то добавлялся как есть?
   ``` if (massage[i] == alfavit[j])
            {
                break;
            }
      else {massage[i] = massage[i]}```

Comment: @RiTick `orig[i] = massage[i]` (massge - массаж, message - сообщение) Надо проверку сделать перед `orig[i] = Convert.toChar` в ответе же есть пример. И где `else` присваиваете `orig[i] = massage[i]`

Comment: Давайте в соц сети спишемся, дабы посвятиться в мою проблему теперь)

Comment: @RiTick я думаю в этом нет смысла, перечитайте еще раз ответ и комментарии. Или про основы языка. И я уверен вы все поймете. Удачи! :)